# Make two columns in Mobile View for Woocommerce Category Archieve page

Tags: css, mobile, woocommerce, responsive-design

I am currently doing it for this page : https://theonlineprinting.com/shop/

For the product category list page (in mobile) I made it well to display 2 columns

But for main category list (shop page), not successful to display into 2 column

Setting the width and float to left doesn't do the fix

Answer (score 1):

In here:

[image]

Change `col-12`s to `col-6`.

Result:

[image]